# No mobile support with svelte-on-solana/wallet-adapter should I switch?

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I'm currently working on a website in Svelte, I just spent 1 day adding mobile support for the website. The only wallet adapter for Solana for Svelte currently is [svelte-on-solana/wallet-adapter](https://github.com/svelte-on-solana/wallet-adapter). Though when I tested for mobile it didn't want to connect. Is there any temporary fixes or should I wait for the owners to add it or should I just simply port my app to React?

Comment: Please provide the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, The issue was that I needed a https conenction to test in phantom mobile, sadly there is no option for testing to remove this option.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, Apperently localhost testing doesn't work on phantom mobile and it needs a secure https connection.